# How can I install maven coordinates using init script?

Tags: azure, maven, databricks

I need to install the below maven coordinates on the clusters using databricks init scripts.

1. coordinate: `com.microsoft.azure:synapseml_2.12:0.11.2` from repo https://mmlspark.azureedge.net/maven
2. coordinate: `com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.2.0` with default repo

I'm able to do this on the cluster using the UI easily. But I would like to install it using the init script so that it is maintainable and reusable by others as well. And I don't have terraform. So need a solution that can be done with init script only

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you using the databricks unity Catalog?

Comment: Hi @DileeprajnarayanThumula No. We are not using databricks unity catalog